# Symfony / Doctrine - Relation ManyToMany - Does exist annotation to say "delete the entity if there is no one connected anymore"?

Tags: php, symfony, orm, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have a blog where people can use hashtag in articles.
The relation that I use is ManyToMany because it can have multiple hashtags used in multiple articles.

When I delete an article, I remove all hashtags of the aricle. I just make removeHashtag with the arrayCollection. It works well, however, I would like to delete the hashtag entity from the database if this hashtag is not use anymore by any other articles.

My article entity :

```
/**
 * Article
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="article")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Moodress\Bundle\PosteBundle\Entity\PosteRepository")
 */
class Article
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Moodress\Bundle\UserBundle\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text")
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="date_creation", type="datetime")
     */
    private $dateCreation;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Moodress\Bundle\FashtagBundle\Entity\Hashtag", cascade={"persist"})
     */
     private $hashtags;

    /**
     * Constructor
     */
     public function __construct()
     {
       $this->dateCreation = new \Datetime();
       $this->hashtags = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
     }
   // Getters and setters
 }
```

My hashtag entity :

```
/**
 * Hashtag
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="fashtag")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Moodress\Bundle\FashtagBundle\Entity\FashtagRepository")
 */
class Fashtag
{
    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="fashtag_name", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $hashtagName;

  //Getters and setters
}
```

Is it possible to delete the Hashtag Entity automatically if it's not use by other article, by using annotations of Doctrine ?
Or after removing the hashtag, should I check by my self if there is any article using this hashtag, and remove by myself the entity ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I faced exactly the same issue. [HERE THE QUESTION AND ANSWER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27506876/deleting-entities-in-cascade-not-working-in-manytomany-relation/27514403?noredirect=1#comment43470237_27514403)  on this subject I posted.

To sum up with my understanding of the probleme is that: **YES, you will have to remove all "out of date" hashtag records manually.** There are no annotations that can provide this effect... unfortunately. (You can see on my post the effect of the annotations *cascade={"remove"}*, *orphanRemoval=true* and *ondelete="CASCADE"* in a ManyToMany relation [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27506876/deleting-entities-in-cascade-not-working-in-manytomany-relation/27514403?noredirect=1#comment43470237_27514403) )

Anyway I would be interested if you could share you controller code to achieved the wanted behavior.

thanks